# wix 3.7 set property based on script/logic/code

Tags: regex, string, properties, wix

We have developed a pretty comprehensive wix installer msi package, which includes some 10+ c# custom actions.

My problem is that I have yet to figure out how to programmatically "set" a property.

Basically what I want to do is to parse an existing property into a new property.

This parsing would be nice to do in c#, but could also be done in RegEx, JavaScript or w/e.

However I am unable to do this from my c# custom actions ("Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action") and as far as I can read I can only change a property from a type 51 custom action. However a type 51 cannot use my c# custom actions. So its catch 22.

Can anyone give give me an example on how to perform the following in wix:
Perform a regular expression/string manipulation using the value of one property and setting another with the result.

It seems obvious to me that this should be possible, but after a lot of searching I am still in the dark.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit #1:
After 3 years of working with wix, I still feel like an amateur, but here goes:
I thought the only way to send properties and work with them in a custom action was this pattern:

```
 <CustomAction Id="CA.SetCreateMessageQueueProperty"
                  Property="CA.CreateMessageQueue"
                  Value="MsmqData=.\Private$\[MYAPPLICATIONNAME]/ObservationReportingService.svc,Observation delivery queue"
                  Return="check"/>
    <CustomAction Id="CA.CreateMessageQueue" 
                  BinaryKey="BI.CA" 
                  DllEntry="CreateMessageQueue" 
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="no"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CA.SetCreateMessageQueueProperty"
              After="InstallFiles"/>
      <Custom Action="CA.CreateMessageQueue" After="CA.SetCreateMessageQueueProperty">
        <![CDATA[((&FE.Afs=3) AND NOT (!FE.Afs=3))]]>
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

---

In the custom action c# assembly:

```
[CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CreateMessageQueue(Session session)
        {
            return session.DoCustomAction("CreateMessageQueue",
                () =>
                    {
                        string msmqData = session.ExtractString("MsmqData");

                        //create actual message queue
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

---

```
internal static ActionResult DoCustomAction(this Session session, string name, Action action)
        {
            session.Log("Begin " + name);
            session.Log("session.CustomActionData.Count:" + session.CustomActionData.Count);
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                session.Log(string.Format("Exception: {0}\nInner Exception: {1}", ex, ex.InnerException));
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you really need a deffered custom action? They are intended to perform updates of the environment and not some calculations of the properties. If I understand correctly, all properties should be set before deffered script execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, your code would look something like this:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult MyCustomAction(Session session)
{
  string property = session["PROPERTYNAME"];
  session["PROPERTYNAME"] = "Look at me!";
  return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

The [`session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object has access to the install database and all its tables. And using its indexer, you can get and set any property in the property table.

You also need a small .config file describing the .NET runtime:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

A lot cleaner than the [C++ alternative](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book) using [`MsiGetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`MsiSetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hopefully, this helps. You can find everything I just wrote in [this WiX tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial), most notably [this page](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/how-to-manage).

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, I had already tried this and ended up with the "Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action" error. I guess it have something to do with how I call the CA from the wix xml. Unfortunately your webpage is in my companys ban list because of malware, so I will have to check from home when I get there. (our companys filter is very overzealous, it also banned Rob Menchings blog for a year)

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen What's the value of your custom action's Execute attribute?

Comment: Dear sir. Sorry for keeping this hanging, I had a hard time formulating a response. I have edited my initial question (Edit#1) showing how I call all my custom actions (example create message queue). Is there a chance I could get you to edit your answer to show me the Wix xml callsite?

Comment: Not all of them in the InstallExecute sequence, but rest is boilerplate for my code.

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen In this case, you'll want a [deferred custom action](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/at-a-later-stage), as Natalie Carr pointed out. However, I fail to see why you'd need to roll out a deferred action to set a property. By that time, the installation is almost done; you no longer have access to the install database. Most importantly, you lose access to the `session` object. The purpose of deferred actions is to change the system directly or to call another system service. I'd recommend switching your action to be immediate.

Comment: Guess its time to get my hands dirty with some code again. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does anybody have an idea why this fails when the msi is run without elevated privileges even tho the custom action is deferred and non impersonate? It returns error 1626 on that very line it sets the property value

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking you are trying to retrieve an existing property and assign it to a new one during a deferred custom action.

```
<CustomAction Id="SetProperty" Return="check" Property="NameOfCustomActionYouAreUsingToRetrieveProperty" Value="[PROPERTY]"></CustomAction>
```

As deferred custom actions in the `InstallExecuteSequence` cannot access the installer properties we have to add the property to `CustomActionData`.

I wrote my custom actions in C++ but I will post the code and you will get an idea to change it to C# code.

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall NameOfCustomActionYouAreUsingToRetrieveProperty(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
LPWSTR szValueBuf = NULL;

hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "NameOfCustomActionYouAreUsingToRetrieveProperty");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"CustomActionData",&szValueBuf);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get CustomActionData");

hr = MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "NEWPROPERTY",  szValueBuf);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to set the new property");

LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);     
}
```